# Set CSS Background color based on element contained in sibling

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML and for the life of me cannot figure out how to get the style to behave how I'd like.

```
<span>
    <span>
        <input id="myRadio" name="tab" role="radio" aria-checked="false" type="radio">
    </span>
    <label for="myRadio">Label</label>
<span>
```

I would like to be able to change the background color of the label or the outer span whenever the Radio Button is selected. I am not able to change the HTML since it is generated server side, otherwise I'd remove the `span` that surrounds the `input` and then use a sibling selector.

Is there any way to accomplish this without the use of javascript? I've got a feeling I won't be able to since there's no parent selector but I wanted to ask before giving up on the idea.

Comment: You either need to use javascript or to change the HTML.

Comment: @ksav I'd change the HTML if I could - it's the HTML generated from an Oracle ADF component. Thank you for the input though.

Comment: Hello, I saw your question and I started looking for an answer, but when I thought I had blocked the answers here, and I was not allowed to comment because I did not have enough reputation. But I saved my solution to comment when I could.

I think the question could continue if it were something like "how to put a background on a parent element too".

Comment: First of all, this solution is kind of a hacking, you really can not change a parent element with the current CSS3, maybe with CSS4 to do that, but there's a way to color the background anyway, using
 ": before" or ": after", along with ": ckecked", so we create a new element every time it is checked, see my example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Byte/7fb26ayq/

Comment: Now let's take the considerations, first, the ": before" element will be over the radio / checkbox button, so I suggest putting a transparent background color to not cover it.
Secondly, most values ​​need to be fine-tuned, as we're trying to put a box underneath a parent element, we can not get the full width, so it needs to be set by thinking of the unit as pixels, for example. I do not know how right the final version is on your page so I could not fine-tune it for you, all these values ​​can change: height, width, padding, background, top and left.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @KevynTuleuDourado This should work for me! Thank you very much!